# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on ngOnInit with Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I'm trying to achieve something pretty simple:
Display data given by a service in my component.

**So here is what I have that used to work:**

In my component:

```
...

dataSet: String[];

ngOnInit(){
  this._service.getDataId().then(data => this.dataSet = data);
}

...
```

In my service:

```
...

getDataId(){
  return this.http.get(adress).toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as String[])
    .catch(this.handleError);
} // return a Promise<String[]>

...
```

In the view:

```
... 

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of dataset">
    {{ data['id'] }}
  </li>
</ul>

...
```

**But now**, I've changed the service function to get more data.
I get an *ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError* since then.
Here is the change in the service:

```
...

getMoreData() {
  const result: Map<string, String[]> = new Map();
  return this.http.get(this.adress).toPromise()
    .then((response) => {
      return Promise.all(Array.from(response.json())
      .map(id => {
        return this.http.get(this.adress + '/' + id').toPromise()
        .then((rep) => {
          result.set(domain['@href'], rep.json() as String[]);
        }).catch(this.handleError)
      })
    );
  })
  .then(() => result)
  .catch(this.handleError);
} // return a Promise<Map<string, String[]>>

...
```

This raise an error even if the data is correctly displayed.
I've tried a few workaround (setTimeout, ChangeDetectorRef)  but I don't even know why this was working and is not anymore since both functions are returning a `Promise<Stuff>`.

I'm also aware that I need to initialize my attribute like this in the component to avoid the null error when the view is loading:

```
this.moreData: Map<string, String[]> = new Map();
```

And this might also cause my issue, but how am I supposed to do then ?

*---*
*Project using*
*Angular 4.2.2*
*Typescript 2.3.4*

Comment: The article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains this behavior in great details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, this is related with this issue: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17725

The Map<> structure is here the problem since it creates a new Iterator every time when you use it in your view (ex: when using .entries)

A workaround can be found in the link above.